# Passing URL params to a standalone VBscript?

Tags: vbscript

Lets say in Internet Explorer you're calling the script, which resides on a network share via

```
file://///server/path/to/script.vbs
```

But that script has arguments. How to pass it those arguments? If this is not possible is there another Windows scripting language that supports this? Thanks

Comment: Don't really understand. Need more info. Is it you have a web page which contains a link to a program on your network you wish to "click and run" ?

Comment: That's correct. It's within an <a> tag embedded in a web page. From Internet Explorer it will run the script but there seems to be no way to pass the script arguments.

Comment: It's not possible. VBScript parameter applies only to *Windows Scripting Host*. If used in a web browser, you'll need to change the main code block in that script into a function, then call that function with its parameter in a separate `SCRIPT` tag.

Comment: The script does things with files, which browser scripts tend to not like. It also brings up a new MS Outlook e-mail which I'm not sure the browser would be willing to do either. Perhaps there is a different Windows scripting language that will permit this?

Answer (score 0):

I know you ask to do this from Internet Explorer, but have you consider [HTML Application (see Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) by renaming your web page from filename.html to filename.hta? That way your HTML page will run with full privileges and any SCRIPT you wish to embed in it will have full privileges.